# How can i get the "Enable Enhanced Profile List Views" check box value in apex code

Tags: visualforce, list-view

Wanted to show profile list view page on a custom link hence tried to get the checkbox value for "Enable Enhanced Profile List Views" but i'm not able to get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't supported but it's not a half bad stop gap to scrape the page if you're logged in as an admin:

```
public Boolean isEnhancedProfileListViewsEnabled() {
    String ui = new PageReference('/ui/setup/org/UserInterfaceUI').getContent().toString();
    return ui.contains('checked="checked" id="enhancedProfileMgmt"');
}
```

[image: profile-ui]

You can even provide a link in your install guide or configuration context to "help" them set this up:

```
public PageReference doEnableProfileListViews() {
    PageReference setup = new PageReference('/ui/setup/org/UserInterfaceUI');
    setup.getParameters().put('enhancedProfileMgmt', '0');
    setup.getParameters().put('saveURL', '/home/home.jsp');
    setup.getParameters().put('save', '1');
    return setup;
}
```

This is a much friendlier experience than a 12 step program the user has to follow from a PDF.